# I need to rewrite mixin from scss to less

Tags: sass, less

I need mixin which checks dir (ltr or rtl) of all parents nodes.
I have it in SCSS but I need it in LESS, and I can't rewrite it. Does somebody know how to write it in LESS?

I tried

```
.rtl when (dir="rtl"){
}
```

It is SCSS

```
@mixin rtl {
    @if $include-rtl {
        @at-root [dir="rtl"] #{&} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less

```
@include-rtl: true;

.rtl(@rules) when (@include-rtl) {
  [dir="rtl"] & {
    @rules();
  }
}

a b c {
  color: red;

  .rtl({color: green});
}
```

Compiles to

```
a b c {
  color: red;
}
[dir="rtl"] a b c {
  color: green;
}
```